# Print stdout subprocess Popen and retain formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess.Popen` to call an installation script. However, when I pipe the output to the terminal, via `print`, it looses any of the formatting from the installation script output. For example, all terminal colors are gone and the download progress bar comes out on multiple lines.

Here's my code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    [script],
    shell=True,
    cwd=script_dir,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    env={
        'WORKSPACE': build_dir
    })
with process.stdout:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line)
```

And a sample of the output (which is usually displayed as a progress bar):

```
You need to run "nvm install 4.2.2" to install it before using it.
Downloading and installing node v4.2.2...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.2/node-v4.2.2-darwin-x64.tar.gz...

                                                                          0.0%
                                                                          1.0%
###                                                                        4.6%
#######                                                                   10.5%
#############                                                             18.8%
###################                                                       26.5%
########################                                                  34.1%
##############################                                            41.9%
###################################                                       49.7%
#########################################                                 57.4%
##############################################                            65.2%
####################################################                      73.0%
##########################################################                80.8%
###############################################################           88.5%
#####################################################################     96.3%
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to call 'iter'. In fact, it complained when I tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664026/4303984) because it's expecting a string, not bytes.

This works to redirect the exact same output:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in process.stdout:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`print` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) prints additional newline at the end. Use [`sys.stdout.write`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) instead:

```
import sys

...    

with process.stdout:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        sys.stdout.write(line)  # <--
        sys.stdout.flush()      # <--
```

BTW, you can just use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) without capturing stdout, stderr output unless you want to process the output in your program:

```
subprocess.call(
    [script],
    shell=True,
    cwd=script_dir,
    env={
        'WORKSPACE': build_dir
    })
```

Comment: You're right that `sys.stdout.write` doesn't add the newline, however, it still makes each step of the progress bar appear on their own line. It seems like the terminal ANSI escape codes are being removed at some point.

Comment: After some more digging, it looks like the ANSI escape code are simply not preserved when using `subprocess.PIPE`. Unfortunately, I do need to process some of the output, so I can't just use `subprocess.call`.